# Cast to a type from the type name as a string

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I have an existing base type and I would like to cast it to a derived type base upon the name of the type as a string, so something like this:

```
public void DoStuffInDerivedType(string derivedName) {
   (base as Type.GetType(derivedName)).DoThisThing();
}
```

I'm pretty sure this can't be done but would be good to know for sure.  Thanks

EDIT: I understand that I could construct the object using reflection from the type name but I want use an existing object.  And also I know this is generally a bad idea.  However I wanted to use this for a SpecFlow BDD Feature.

Comment: Consider of using `Relection`

Comment: Why do you want to cast? can't you call it dynamically? e.g. `((dynamic)this).DoThisThing();`

Comment: If `derivedName` isn't know at compile-time, how can the compiler check that `DoThisThing` is a valid method on all the possible `derivedName`s you could pass to that method? Why are you trying to do the cast? Have you considered using virtual methods / interfaces instead?

Comment: Which existing object? Can you provide a better code sample? Try also to explain why are you trying to do this.

Comment: @Luaan It's a BBD test so the type name is a string from a feature file.

Comment: Something like this is totally valid if you're de-serializing stuff IMO.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'll repeat the advice that you probably don't need to do this, but because I have done this operation before:

`Convert.ChangeType(ItemToCast, Type.GetType(stringNameOfType)))`

Should work for you.

Comment: This is nice, but it only works if the object implements `IConvertible`. Classes like `Exception` don't unfortunately.

Comment: i had to put a cast in front , which pretty much brings you back to typing the type out, which puts you back at square one. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you *need* to cast it to the derived type. You should be able to cast it to the base type and use the shared interface (be it a base class or literal Interface) to perform whatever you want done.

If not, consider adding the behavior as an interface requirement so you *can* do it that way.

Finally: the one possibility where you'd *need* to do it this way is if you're overriding the casts...in which case I'm almost certain you can't do this without some heavy duty reflection.