# C# How to cast from object to a type whose name is available as string

Tags: c#

I get an object from a **message broker** (RabbitMQ) which has a signature similar to the following:

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string OriginalMessageType { get; set; }
    public object OriginalMessage { get; set; }
}
```

*Background information*

I do have a C# DLL containing all message type definitions. The messages are not designed for C# specifically, since consumers are written in several programming languages. So the message objects do not contain Generics and other C# goodies. With C# I use the EasyNetQ library to serialize/deserialize messages and as wrapper around the RabbitMQ client driver.

**Question / Problem**

Is there any way in C# to **cast / convert** the `OriginalMessage` property from `object` to an *instance of its original type*? The **type information is provided as string** in the `OriginalMessageType` property.

I tried something like this (which of course doesn't work...) in my message handler method

```
public static Task ProcessErrorMessage(IMessage<ErrorMsg> message, MessageReceivedInfo info)
{
    var t = Type.GetType(message.Body.OriginalMessageType);
    var origMsg = (t)message.Body.OriginalMessageType; //get the original message which caused the error
    var someProperty = origMsg.SomeProperty;
    // etc.
    // process the message using properties of origMsg
    // ...

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: casting is a compile time construct.

Comment: perhaps you should decorate with interfaces?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067071/cast-to-a-type-from-the-type-name-as-a-string

Comment: The second line is casting the `OriginalMessageType`, shouldn't it be casting the `OriginalMessage`?

Comment: Is the `object` in the property is the actual object you want to cast in ?

Comment: If you don't know type at compile time how do you know that `SomeProperty` exists on that type? You can implement an interface and cast to that interface as mentioned by @DanielA.White

Comment: Since this is pretty much daily question... ThommyB - could you please explain why do you expect compiler to know that `SomeProperty` exist on that type *at compile time*? Maybe someone can come up with explanation to dispel this misunderstanding so others could understand it too...

Comment: You could possibly just use `dynamic` of course...

Comment: Or they could cast the correct member variable.  @AlexeiLevenkov - either they're confusing `var` and `dynamic` or they expect when you cast into a `var` you get a well-defined object...

Comment: Thanks to everybody, but I think there is **no way of doing it**.
`dynamic` looked promising, but I need access to properties, and this is only possible with compile time constructs. So this is unfortunately no solution.
Interfaces would work but I cannot change the protocol (message definitions) easily in a distributed application.
I have a protocol of sent messages on a database. Message objects are stored there in a JSON representation. Looks like this is the only way: make a 'detour' and query the database, and read the JSON data...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you can split your task into 2 steps:

1. Create a type of the string using `OriginalMessageType`
2. Convert an object `OriginalMessage` to desired type

I guess you can just have a `switch` statement and cast an object to a specific type, but your task could be different, so

#### Step #1

To create a type from the string:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("YourNamespace.YourClass, YourAssembly");
```

You can use just the name of the type if the type is in `mscorlib` or the calling assembly:

```
Type myType1 = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```

Please see [`Type.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) for more information.

#### Step #2

To convert an object I would suggest to use `Convert.ChangeType` which is

> Returns an object of the specified type whose value is equivalent to
>   the specified object.

So it can look like this

```
dynamic origMsg = (dynamic) Convert.ChangeType(OriginalMessage, YourType);
```

#### Small example

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class A
    {
        public int P1 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A myvariable = new A
            {
                P1 = 1,
            };

            object obj = myvariable;
            string typename = "ConsoleApp12.A";

            Type type = Type.GetType(typename);

            dynamic origMsg = (dynamic)Convert.ChangeType(obj, type);

            Console.WriteLine(origMsg.P1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately not, see my comment above. It may be a solution in other situations. Also I noticed that the `Type.GetType()` returns `null` even though I gave a fully qualified assembly name. My server is running in a docker container on UNIX, it should find it but it seems not to. 
But retrieving the information from the protocol on the database seems to work.

Comment: @ThommyB what if you cast it to specific typed based on the typename ? Like if typename  == "ClassA" => ClassA myoject = (ClassA)originalObject ... Another possible option for you is a JObject. It's not exactly what you need, but it may fit (depending on your requirements)